# Rename "web" folder in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to rename the "web" folder to "html" in symfony 1.4, unfortunately searching for documentation on this has lead me nowhere except for how this would be accomplished in 1.0, which does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, you don't have to rename it. You can just create a symbolic link (unless you're running windows):

```
ln -s web html
```

If you still want to change the web folder name than you could do it in your project's ProjectConfiguration class by overloading setRootDir():

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setRootDir($rootDir)
  {
    parent::setRootDir($rootDir);

    $this->setWebDir($rootDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'html');
  }
}
```

Comment: kuba, I have given my answer as well, but I don't believe yours will work -- you need the directory separator: `$this->setWebDir($rootDir . '/html');` because symfony doesn't automatically have it.

Answer (score 5):

kuba's answer is along the right lines, but I think it is cleaner to use `setWebDir` within `setup`:

```
class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
    public function setup()
    {
        $this->setWebDir($this->rootDir . '/html');
    }
}
```

I would generally prefer not to use a symlink, because it clutters up the root folder.

Comment: Original setRootDir() method in sfProjectConfiguration ALWAYS overwrites the web dir and several other variables. If setRootDir() is called later than setup() (it can be, it's public) than it will change the web dir back to the original value.

Comment: You're right, my apologies.  I noticed that `sf_web_dir` wasn't in the one `sfConfig::add` call and failed to notice that below was a `setWebDir` call!