# Why Symfony 2 installed into web root?

Tags: php, symfony

I am looking at downloading and learning Symfony 2. I haven't really looked at a PHP framework before.

I'm aware discussion isn't allowed on here, but I'm pretty certain my question isn't subjective and there's an obvious clear answer to my question.

Why is Symfony 2 downloaded into the public web root?

Surely it should be non-public and only HTML/CSS etc should be public?

Obviously I'm wrong, but would appreciate the reason for this.

Doesn't that mean that somebody can go to http://mysite.com/symfony/classes/database.php etc. (not a specific URL, but just to highlight my point) and run various scripts? Obviously that's probably just a class file, but it still doesn;t seem right to me.

Also, I want to run say 5 or 6 different sites on the same framework. If it's installed in the web root then doesn't that mean I need to install the entire Symfony code base for each site (in each site's web root) - where as if it was hosted outside the web root then each site can reference that (e.g. '../../symfony/classes/database.php' etc.) (as long as on all sites are on the same server).

I must me missing something very clear and obvious.

Comment: If you aren't looked framework before Symfony why you not try maybe lighter version as Codeigniter or Zend framework?

Comment: I'm no expert but I believe Zend as very complicated. I would appreciate advice on the question though. Thanks,

Comment: Zend is very complicated on version 1. You should focus on new version 2. Symfony is more complicated than Zend 2.

Comment: To answer your second question, I think there was a change of strategy whilst symfony 1.x was the current version. Sharing a copy of the library makes building a new server trickier - it is more convenient to just checkout from svn/git including externals/submodules for the framework. Disk space is cheap, so the slight wastage isn't much of an issue. Also, when upgrading a minor version of the framework, it is best to do this one at a time (in case of live problems) rather than risk it with all sites at once!

Comment: Closed as not a real question. WTF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While many frameworks do place all their code in web root, Symfony does not.

Instead, the standard distribution has a /web folder, which you should make your webroot.

If you are on a server where you cannot configure the webroot to be within your Symfony project folder, you can instead use a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) between the webroot folder and the Symfony web folder. This is common practice for things such as shared hosting plans.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got it now.

Comment: Can you tell why the web folder should be the document root of the virtual host ?

Comment: @mlwacosmos Best answer is security reasons - unless apache is configured wrong, anything outside document root can't be accessed directly.

Comment: In my firm they dont use the web directory as document root anayway you cannot access anything else but web directory

Comment: it is not the same finally ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with Symfony, but I believe that it has a `.htaccess` file in the root directory, which probably has a line like this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ web/app.php
```

meaning that all requests to the root directory get redirected to the /web/app.php file.  Alas, nobody can go anywhere except for that file.

As others have pointed out, in a production environment you should point your webroot to the /web directory for more stringent security considerations. My answer above was just trying to point out why it works the way it does out-of-the box.

Comment: Why the downvote? I understand that I may be wrong, but at least explain. :)

Comment: Down-vote please explain as this sounded right to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you put your framework data on server it's want be on public. Only folder `public` is pointed on VPS server via Virtual Hosts and see as public. Symfony public folder is `web` so you should this point to Virtual host to loading index.php

Look at this more about: [Rename "web" folder in Symfony 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946840/rename-web-folder-in-symfony-1-4)

Example how to set a document root on symfony2: [symfony2 installation instruction help please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815285/symfony2-installation-instruction-help-please)

Version 2 is similar as 1.4 because you need only point to path.

Comment: Is this the case for Symfony2 as well?